# how to use .htaccess to silently read from the cache, if the file exists? is this possible?

Tags: .htaccess

i have this file structure:

```
/
/index.php
/test.php

/example/foo/bar/test.php

/cache/index.htm
/cache/test.htm
/cache/foo/bar/test.htm
```

everything in /cache/* is a flat file (.htm) of the generated php files.

Basically what i want to do is this -

- a user requests `/index.htm` (users
  will never see a .php in their url
  even if its made on the fly)
- .htaccess checks if `/cache/index.htm`
  exists. if so, it reads from that
  file.
- if `/cache/index.htm` doesn't
  exist, it serves index.php

another example

- a user requests `/example/foo/bar/test.htm`
- if `/cache/example/foo/bar/test.htm` exists, it reads from it
- if it doesn't exist, the user is shown `/example/foo/bar/test.php` (but doesn't see the .php extension)

is this possible at all in .htaccess?

thanks

(btw i make the cache files elsewhere. so no need to making them on the fly)

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the only kind of check you want to do is an existence check, it should be possible with the following [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) rule set:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Check if a PHP page was requested
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s/[^\s]+\.php
# If so, redirect to the non-cache .htm version
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ /$1.htm [R=301,L]

# Check if the file exists in the cache
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/$0 -f
# If it does, rewrite to the cache file
RewriteRule ^.*$ /cache/$0 [L]

# Check that the file doesn't exist (we didn't go to the cache)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# Check that the request hasn't been rewritten to the PHP file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$
# If both are true, rewrite to the PHP file
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm$ /$1.php
```