# Rewrite based on if a file exists or not

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am implementing a cache on my database driven website.
I save cache files to /cache/ as id.html

I have urls like http://www.example.com/view/article/id/12338.html

Now i need to check if this 12338.html file exists in cache or not. If it exist, it should be server else it should be rewritten to /viewArticle.php?id=12338

So here is what i need:

1)Extract id number e.g. 12338 in this case.

2)Check if /cache/id.html exist e.g /cache/12338.html in this case and serve it and exit.

3)Or serve /viewArticle.php?id=12338

What rewrite conditions and rules do i need? Particularly for extracting the id from request filename.

Comment: Did you see this:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748863/how-to-use-htaccess-to-silently-read-from-the-cache-if-the-file-exists-is-thi

Comment: yeah but how do i check for id.html?

Comment: The answer in the link has comments that describe each line. There's a line that is commented `Check if the file exists in the cache`

Answer (score 0):

Put this .htaccess file in your server document root

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteRule view/article/id/(.*).html$ /cache/$1.html [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^cache(.*)\.html$ /viewArticle.php?id=$1  [NC]
</IfModule>
```